# How do I convert from unixtime to a date/time in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

So, the setup is that I have the time, in seconds, since the epoch and I want to turn this into a date I can actually understand. 
How do I do this in Haskell? If it is possible, how would I extract days/hours/minutes out of this new encoding?

Comment: As a note, that's often called [unixtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unixtime)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Data.Time.Clock.POSIX](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/time/1.4.0.1/doc/html/Data-Time-Clock-POSIX.html) has `posixSecondsToUTCTime` (you can convert another numeric type to the input expected `POSIXTime` with `realToFrac`).

[Data.Time.Calendar](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/time/1.4.0.1/doc/html/Data-Time-Calendar.html) has a lot of the things you need to extract day, month, etc from the `Day` that forms a part of `UTCTime`, the rest of the package has other useful utilities.

Example:

```
Prelude> import Data.Time.Format.ISO8601
Prelude Data.Time.Format.ISO8601> import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX 
Prelude Data.Time.Format.ISO8601 Data.Time.Clock.POSIX> iso8601Show $ posixSecondsToUTCTime $ 100
"1970-01-01T00:01:40Z"
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [time](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time) library which is installed by default:

```
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX
import Data.Time.Format

main = print $ formatTime defaultTimeLocale  "%c" $ posixSecondsToUTCTime 10
```

The library has wide range of date manipulation functions (e.g. date subtraction, getting components such as day-month etc). If you want to extract components just for converting them to string you can use `formatTime`.

Comment: Errors with `Could not find module ‘System.Locale’`.

Comment: It is no longer needed.